# UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad dismiss keyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

How is a user suppose to indicate that he/she is done typing if the keyboard is of type UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad? There's no return/done button so how do I know the user wants to dismiss the keyboard?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After researching this problem for a while, I found no really satisfactory answers. Some solutions hack a "Done" button, but that doesn't work well for localized applications. My apps don't use any words so I definitely don't want a "Done" button.

As mentioned by taskinoor it is convenient for editing to end if the view is touched elsewhere. That's what I did, and here is code showing the details:

Creating the textField programmatically:

```
aTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[aTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(c1Update) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
aTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[yourView addSubview:aTextField];
c1Value = aTextField; // I like to keep a pointer for UI updates, alpha etc.
```

What happens in c1Update:

```
- (void)c1Update {
    [[self brain] setC1:[c1Value.text intValue]]; // update the model
}
```

Gesture recognizer on view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateViewColors];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

- (void) viewTapped {
    if (c1Value.isFirstResponder) {[c1Value resignFirstResponder];} // dismisses keyboard, which causes c1Update to invoke.
}
```

Comment: That prevents touches on buttons elsewhere in the view

Answer (score 1):

You can either provide a cancel/hide button (outside the keypad) or hide that when touched anywhere outside the keypad. These two are common practices.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it might help you 
hide the keypad when touched the screen.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}
```